# Python Flask retrieve POST data from AngularJS AJAX

Tags: python, angularjs, json, ajax, flask

I am using Angular AJAX call to send data to my Flask backend for natural language processing.

AJAX code:

```
$scope.processText = function(){

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/processText",
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            'message': "this is my message",
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        $scope.message = "";
    });
}
```

I'm able to retrieve an Object {message: "this is my message"} but unfortunately I'm could not access to the key by typing request.data.message.

Flask route

```
@app.route('/processText', methods=['POST'])

def analyzeText():
    if request.method == "POST":

        data = json.loads(request.data)
        return data         #error : "dict is not callable"
        return data.message #error : "'bytes' object has no attribute 'message'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
from flask import jsonify, request
...
message = request.json['message']
return jsonify({'some_message':message})
```

If you are confused, you cannot interchange `request.json.message` and `request.json['message']` in Python. The latter is the only option. It will work in Django templates, but that's another story.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jsonify to return the object since jsonify creates a flask.Response() object that automatically has the Content-Type header.

Try using this: `return jsonify(data)`

Alternatively, if you want to return the string (value of message), you can just go ahead and return the value as you would any dict value i.e `return data['message']`